# Output Javascript document.write in XSL

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xhtml, document.write

I'm having major trouble to output a document.write() javascript through my XSL page. 
(It's part of a 3rd party external tracking code snippet)

My desired output is:

```
  document.write('<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+(document.location.protocol=='https:'?'s':'')+'://'+ia_link+'"></sc'+'ript>');
```

An this is my complete Code:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

    var url="someurl.js";
    var blablabla="some-dynamic-values"; 
    var ia_link=url+'?parameter='+blablabla;

</script>

<script>
   <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//:'+ia_link+'"></script>')]]></xsl:text>
</script>

<noscript>
  <img src="http://url.php?blablabla=some-dynamic-values" width="1" height="1" />
</noscript>
```

I've tried several things outoutting the document.write() element...with the above `<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">` not-working solution, the html gets outputted corrupted (two `</script>` tags)

**--> How to output the document.write with the script tags correctly?**

Comment: It's impossible to get ia_link in [CDATA] script

Answer (score 2):

Which browsers do you target? Mozilla browsers like Firefox or SeaMonkey are known not to support `document.write` in the HTML result of a client-side XSLT transformation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#What_about_document.write.3F