# Appending text in a span tag using javascript in a XSLT for XML

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

```
<xsl:for-each select="ColumnName">
 <span>
    <script  type="text/javascript">document.write("thisStringIsGood".replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); }));</script>                           
 </span>
</xsl:for-each>
```

This code is throwing an error:

`InvalidStateError: An attempt was made to use an object that is not, or is no longer, usable`

Trying the same in regular html works

```
 <span>
    <script  type="text/javascript">document.write("thisStringIsGood".replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').replace(/^./, function(str){ return str.toUpperCase(); }));</script>                           
 </span>
```

Comment: I don't think your code is wrong. I guess the error occurs after you write something to replace "ThisStringIsGood". I guess you are not showing us the real code which caused error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that question was already asked and answered here:
[Output Javascript document.write in XSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073158/output-javascript-document-write-in-xsl)

Short summary:

- It is a problem with Mozilla browsers
- Try to identify the browser:
  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XSL_Transformations_in_Mozilla_FAQ#What_about_document.write.3F

Comment: About that question, the answer there is not correct. The real reason is: you cannot use global variable (created in regular js code) in [CDATA] script.